# Does update Cosmos DB TTL container settings will impact on old items?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, ttl

I updated my cosmos db container with this code

```
var containerResponse = await _cosmosContainer.ReadContainerAsync();
            var containerProperties = containerResponse.Resource;
            if (containerProperties.DefaultTimeToLive == null)
            {
                containerProperties.DefaultTimeToLive = 60 * 60 * 24 * 180; // set 180 days default TTL 
                await _cosmosContainer.ReplaceContainerAsync(containerProperties);
            }
```

Does update Cosmos DB TTL container settings will impact on old items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/time-to-live),

> After you set the TTL at a container or at an item level, Azure Cosmos
> DB will automatically remove these items after the time period, since
> the time they were last modified.

Yes it will impact on old items.